# Pulling form information from a table

Tags: php, forms, concrete5

Im working on an ordering system for a client. On the order page is a table that displays all the different vendors and their products and then on that table is a text fields where they can put the quantity of each product they want and when they click checkout it displays the ordered things on a confirm page.
The code for the display is below

```
    <?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");

?> <div class="ccm-ui"><?php
$db= Loader::db();





$query = 'SELECT * FROM Vendors';

$results = $db->getAll($query);
?>
<form name="OrderForm" action="/confirm" method="POST">
 <table stlye="position:relative;"class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Vendor</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                </tr>
<?php
foreach ($results as $vendor) {
?>
<tr>
<td><input style="width:50px" type="text" name="quantities" value="0" size="1"  /></td>
<td><?php echo $vendor['Product'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $vendor['Category'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $vendor['Vendor'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $vendor['Address'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Checkout"<button style="float:right;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
</form>
</div>
```

The only problem i have is that when i try to pull the information it only pulls the value for the last text field instead of all of them. Ideally id like to have an if statement that checks if the text value is more than 0 and then if it is it will display it.

Comment: Are your column names respectively named and capitalized correctly (Product, Category, Vendor, Address)? What do you get if you were to write `echo '<pre>'.print_r($results, true).'</pre>';` before the `foreach()` loop?

Comment: can you post `$db->getall($query)` ?

Comment: It spits out a code view of my table information above the table and it puts it into an array.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vendorID] => 1
            [Product] => HES Packet
            [Category] => UI HES
            [Vendor] => A-Plus Installation, LLC
            [Address] => 150B Park Avenue, ATTN: Nicholas Sackandy, East Hartford, CT 06108
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vendorID] => 2
            [Product] => HES Packet
            [Category] => CLP HES
            [Vendor] => A-Plus Installation, LLC
            [Address] => 150B Park Avenue, Attn: Nicholas Sackandy, East Hartford, CT 06108
        )

)

Comment: I can see no reason that your table wouldn't be getting outputted. Especially since the print_r($results) is showing an array with data in it. If you view the source of the page, do you see the table row markup there? Perhaps it's being hidden by CSS? Seems like something weird going on that's probably unrelated to the actual query.

Comment: ehh... actually I think perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question -- are you saying that you're getting the table to show up on the page but you're having trouble pulling out data from the textboxes AFTER someone has submitted the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your question at first sounds like you're having trouble displaying the table rows, but perhaps the problem you're having is just on the back-end, trying to pull out the data that was submitted from the form? If so, the reason is because all of your textboxes have the same exact name (`quantities`).

To solve this, you can add square brackets to the textbox name and put some kind of product ID in the brackets, which will then be converted to an array when you process the posted form.

For example, on the front-end form you could have this:

```
<input style="width:50px" type="text" name="quantities[<?php echo $vendor['Product'];?>]" value="0" size="1"  />
```

Then in the back-end when you process the form, you'll get this:

```
$quantities = $_POST['quantities'];
foreach ($quantities as $product_name => $quantity) {
    echo "The quantity for product: " . $product_name . " is: " $quantity;
}
```

(Obviously you'll want to do something other than `echo` that stuff out in the back-end, but hopefully that demonstrates how to extract the POST'ed data.)